# How to remove first and last elements of array?

Tags: javascript

```
const myOldArr = [2, 3, 6];
const newArr = myOldArr.pop().shift();
```

Why does doing this give me a TypeError? Is there a way to do this without a loop? I want the new array to be stored inside a variable so the remaining numbers that don't get removed are stored inside an array of some sort.

Comment: `pop` [returns the _element_ that you popped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop). It is not an array that you can then use `shift` on.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

`.pop()` returns the last element form your array and so `.shift()` won't work,

If you want to keep the `myOldArr` and create a new one without the first and last element, you can do this by using [`.slice(1, -1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const myOldArr = [2, 3, 6];
const myNewArr = myOldArr.slice(1, -1);
console.log(myNewArr);
```

Or, if you don't mind moifying the original array, you can do this by not chaining both methods:

```js
const myOldArr = [2, 3, 6];
myOldArr.pop()
myOldArr.shift();
console.log(myOldArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use them separately

`Array.pop()` and `Array.shift()` will return a value of array
your trying to use shift in number 6 so it will throw error

```js
const myOldArr = [2, 3, 6];
myOldArr.pop();//last 
myOldArr.shift();//first
console.log(myOldArr)
```

Comment: i know that but I would want to put the remaining number in a separate array

Comment: Please edit your answer and write explicitly what you expect.